# Making a formula a VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I got the following code

```
    =LEFT(A2, MIN(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)))+(((CODE(MID(UPPER(A2),
         ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))), 1))>64)*(CODE(MID(UPPER(A2), 
         ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))), 1))<91))+
         ((CODE(MID(A2, ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))), 1))>47)*
         (CODE(MID(A2,  ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))), 1))<58)))*1E+99)-1)
```

I have this code and a few others, but how can I make it into a macro applicable to my entire workbook? I know its probably the same as a macro in terms of time, but I eventually want to loop it throughout a directory and would help automate a process. Is there a way to make this a macro for my workbook?

Comment: Why not describe what it's supposed to do, instead of asking us to both decode it *and* convert it to VBA?

Comment: A working formula is almost always better than a corresponding macro in terms of time, but the flexibility of a VBA macro might justify the typically small time difference.

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry Tim, its like using left formula on a field but for fields with various lengths and symbols at the end. For example: Tim01_34rw, would be cut to Tim01.

Comment: @JohnColeman , well its fine if its just formula. Whatever you reccommend.

Comment: @Jonathan -- turning something into a VBA macro makes perfect sense. Tim Williams comment suggests one of the reasons -- complex spreadsheet formulas can get to the stage that they are not very readable, which makes them difficult to modify. I was just responding to your statement that it is probably the same in terms of time. VBA is interpreted (after compiling into a byte code) which means that it almost always executes slower than Excel's built-in calculation engine. In most use-cases you are talking about very small fractions of a second, so this isn't a decisive point against your idea.

Comment: I think I am confused.  `ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)))` will always return 1 regardless of the value of A2.  So this formula appears to say: if the first character of A2 is a number or a letter then return A2 otherwise return an empty string.  Is that right or is all that extra stuff that doesn't appear to do anything actually do something?

Comment: I actually got it from someone else, the extra stuff does do stuff for me, whereas what you wrote just returns a 1 for me. Is there a way to do this using indirect to return only the alphanumeric parts of a field?

Answer (score 1):

The crudest quickest way would be something like this:

```
    Range("J2:J5000").Formula = "=LEFT(A2, MIN(ROW(INDIRECT(""1:""&LEN(A2)))+(((CODE(MID(UPPER(A2), ROW(INDIRECT(""1:""&LEN(A2))), 1))>64)*(CODE(MID(UPPER(A2), ROW(INDIRECT(""1:""&LEN(A2))), 1))<91))+((CODE(MID(A2, ROW(INDIRECT(""1:""&LEN(A2))), 1))>47)*(CODE(MID(A2,  ROW(INDIRECT(""1:""&LEN(A2))), 1))<58)))*1E+99)-1)"
```

Which will put your exact formula in the range (and update itself according to the row reference). Obviously the reference to column J can be changed and the 5000 can be made dynamic using rows.count).end(xlup).row but without knowing which columns to play with I just had to take a stab at a crude solution.

However depending on what your "symbols" could be a solution using the split command would most likely be the better choice. Can you post more direction on this? Then I can edit this answer and add a code solution in for that for you.

Also include some sample data and expected results, maybe 10 rows worth to give a good set for testing

For an example of how the split command works select one of the cells with data in it that you need to split on the underscore and go to the debug window in the VBE (CTRL-G) and enter this (including the question mark) then press enter.

```
?split(Activecell.text,"_")(0)
```

Now update the 0 to 1 and press enter. This will show you how this command works, it splits a string to an array based on the delimiter you give it.

EDIT:

This code will do what you want, Notice how Split is being used.

```
Function GetFirstPart(SplitString As String)
Dim PosibleSplits As Variant, X As Long
PossibleSplits = Array("_", "+", "-")
For X = LBound(PossibleSplits) To UBound(PossibleSplits)
    If Len(SplitString) <> Len(Split(SplitString, PossibleSplits(X))(0)) Then
        GetFirstPart = Split(SplitString, PossibleSplits(X))(0)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Use it by pasting the code into a module then in your sheet use it the same as any other formula `=GetFirstPart(A1)` where A1 has the string to split, drag down as far as your data goes.

You can add other delimiters in this line `PossibleSplits = Array("_", "+", "-")`

Comment: Hi Dan, I am trying to extract from Column E (Same col in every workbook and worksheet).  I need the alphanumeric values, so anything  that ISN'T a  letter or number would be removed after the beginning of the string. Ex: Irvega_Dan12, would return Irvega. If that makes sense.

Comment: Some sample data would be, each string separated by spaces `pv01_5y
pv01_7y
pv01_10y
pv01_20y
pv01_30y
pv+200
pv+100
pv+50
pv+25
pv+10
pv+05
pv-01
pv-05
pv-10
pv-25
pv-50
pv-100
pv-200
irvega_exp1y_mat1y
irvega_exp1y_mat2y
irvega_exp1y_mat3y
`

Comment: When I do your VBE suggestion, I get the result I am wanting with 0, and the 1 shows the second part of the string. Ex pv01_3m , with 0 it shows pv01, with 1 it shows 3m.

Comment: OK, based on your sample data I would imagine you can use a for next loop and run a string of splits, one for each possible delimiter (_, -, + etc). Are you comfortable to do this or do you need some help to put it together?

Comment: I would need help , Sorry. So what was the `?split(Activecell.text,"_")(0)` for? using it in the VBE it was able to delimit exactly how I wanted it to.

Comment: Btw Dan, for the macro above is there a way  shift+ctrk+enter  can be added in the macro? It seems to only work when I use that way for when i use that for the forumula way.

Comment: I have updated my original post for you, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the code, So I'm pasting =GetFirstPart(E2) into F2, and my result is #NAME?

Comment: Did you copy the code to a module in the workbook? What is in E2?

Comment: I put it into the Binary file, so I can use without pasting into multiple workbooks. Tried putting it in the actually workbook and get #NAME? . E2 is 'pv01_3m' wanting the result in F2 to be 'pv01'

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by binary file

Comment: the xlsb file, so it is autoloaded in vba. Isnt it used so you can use a macro across multiple workbooks instead of pasting the code into the workbook itself in the vba editor.

Comment: I haven't heard of that before, you can create an addin or possibly use your personal macro workbook

Comment: I use the personal Macro workbook and i get the #name? :(